# Intellij Idea is loading *.class file instead of *.scala from library source

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

My problem is best described with a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, there is a `org.virtuslab:unicorn-core_2.11` dependency loaded in my SBT/Scala project. The jar file with corresponding sources is available as well. For some reason, **Intellij Idea decided to ignore the available source file `Table.scala` and uses the `.class` file instead.** Clearly, all other files are okay.

Obviously, without the information contained in the `.scala` file, Intellij is not able to properly analyze my code and I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol BaseIdRepository` errors (and similar) all over my project.

I manually checked the source package and the `Table.scala` file is there and seems alright. Plus this worked flawlessly until two days ago. I don't know why it broke down. I tried to revert my project using git to an earlier version when this was still working, but no luck.

I tried to both downgrade and upgrade the library, I tried to remove it and add it again, I tried create a completely new project based on existing sources, but once again, no luck.

Just for the record, I'm able to compile and run my project. The only thing that *might* be related is this warning that I get when compiling the project:

```
[warn] /home/tobik/scala/payola-viz/src/app/model/appgen/repository/UsersRepository.scala:7: Could not find any member to link for "BaseIdRepository".
```

Comment: Well the self-type annotation of the Tables trait [does look incorrect](http://i.imgur.com/bb0LEg3.png) for one. I don't think having two bodies for anonymous stuff (`{}{}`) is allowed. At the very least thats why Idea is having problems.

Comment: Hm hmm, I get that underlined as well. But as I said... it worked until two days ago.

Comment: Yeah definitely very odd. The code in the source jar is fine. Have you updated idea or the scala plugin recently? Maybe they introduced a bug of some sort.

Comment: That was my thinking as wall so I tried several different scala plugin versions (I even downgraded back to the 2.* version). No difference.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I added the unicorn sources directly to my code base and manually removed it from the project libraries. I got rid of the errors and it still compiles as the library remains as a dependency inside `build.sbt`. I guess it will break once Intellij synchronizes the project with `build.sbt` but I can just repeat this procedure. To avoid polluting my project, I added the included sources to `.gitignore`. It's an ugly work around. I hope someone will come up with an actual solution...

Comment: I have seen this problem several times. Usually it should work if you check the 'download sources' box when creating an IntelliJ project file from an sbt build file. You might want to try to wipe the project and create it anew from the sbt file, or maybe just check the sbt settings in IntelliJ (make sure 'download sources' is enabled) and refresh the sbt model.

Comment: Well the sources are downloaded and clearly even used. The problem is that for some reason, they are used only partially, some files are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an update for the `Scala` plugin which seems to fix this issue.

---

In case you experience similar problems, this temporary solution worked for me: I added the unicorn sources directly to my code base and manually removed it from the project libraries. I got rid of the errors and it still compiles as the library remains as a dependency inside `built.sbt`. To avoid polluting my project, I added the included sources to `.gitignore`. The workaround broke after a while but all I had to do was repeat the procedure again.